# python: append to end of first line in a text file

Tags: python, loops, text, append

I have a for loop ending in

```
statsG.append(str(mean))
```

and then after the loop

```
np.savetxt(path+'Stats.txt',statsG,'%s')
```

So after two iterations I get a text file with 2 lines of text in the `Stats.txt` file. I'd prefer to have one line of text (i.e. second iteration of for loop appends to end of first iterations output.

Comment: Include the actual code in your question.

Comment: Please reformat your post and use the code syntax highlight, it's unreadable like that

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear, but you can initiate an empty string before the loop, then in each iteration append do it.

```
string_to_save = ''
for line in file:
    string_to_save += line
save_function(file_name, string_to_save)
```

If this is not helpful then edit your question with more details as asked in the comments.

Comment: Strings are immutable and do not have an `append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
mergedString = ','.join(statsG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea I think I asked that poorly. statsG was a list that I was saving as a .txt file. The solution was to np.reshape the list before saving as a string. Thanks for the help